# Как работает вставка JS кода в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Возможно этот вопрос был и раньше (в чем я сомневаюсь) или даже в какой-то степени глупый, но как говорит заголовок вопроса: меня просто интересует как это все работает.

Иначе говоря, как вот этот ниже код вставляет в себя переменную (то есть что в каком скрипте react какое выполняется действие? replace? eval?)
(Если что, это не реальный пример и не стоит его использовать)

```
const link = "https://google.com"; // Опять же, для примера
return (
  <a href={link}>Link Text</a>
//           ^ вот как здесь происходит вставка?
);
```

Comment: вроде eval....... достаточно исходники посмотреть реакта   ........  https://github.com/facebook/react/search?l=JavaScript&p=2&q=eval&type=code   ...... но точные строки и точный файл не скажу..... помню находил

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, судя по примеру - там не про тот js код, про который ты подумал

Comment: стоит начать со [справки по JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)